# Asignar posición de lista a setVideoUri()

Tags: android, recyclerview

estoy intentando activar la selección de elementos de un RecyclerView, es una lista de videos y la idea es que se pueda elegir cual reproducir para lo que he incluido un setOnClickListerner() en el adapter de mi lista, tengo la referencia al archivo pero no se como pasar ese dato al VideoView para que este lo reproduzca...estoy bloqueado y cualquier sugerencia es bienvenida!

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

RecyclerView recycler;
VideoView video;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    recycler = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.RecyclerId);
    recycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false));
    AdapterDatos adapter = new AdapterDatos(DatosRaw.allRawFiles());
    recycler.setAdapter(adapter);

    //********************************VIDEO*****************************************

    video= (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView2);

    video.setVideoURI(Uri.parse());
    video.start();
    MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
    video.setMediaController(mc);

}
```

}

AdapterDatos.java

```
     public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolderDatos holder, int position) {

    holder.asignarDatos(listDatos.get(position));
    final int pos = position;

    holder.dato.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        posicionmarcada = pos;
        notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    });

    if (posicionmarcada==position){

        listDatos.get(position);       //REFERENCIA AL ELEMENTO CLICKADO

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto lo tendrías que realizar dentro de tu Adapter, en el método `onBindViewHolder()`, obtén la referencia del VideoView

```
     public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolderDatos holder, int position) {

    holder.asignarDatos(listDatos.get(position));
    final int pos = position;


    holder.dato.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        posicionmarcada = pos;
        notifyDataSetChanged();

        //*Agrega valor de uri de acuerdo a posición para reproducir video.
        holder.video.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(....));
        holder.video.start();

        }
    });

    if (posicionmarcada==position){

        listDatos.get(position);       //REFERENCIA AL ELEMENTO CLICKADO

    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias ! :)

Comment: Excelente Carlos,  saludos.